# disable filter on magento massaction

Tags: php, magento

I setup magento's massAction for use in an Admin grid, and I would like to know how to get rid of the "filter" dropdown menu that is over the checkboxes that are created for massAction.

Here are a few things I've tried:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('filter', false);
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setData('filter', false);
$this->getMassactionBlock()->unsetData('filter');
```

Not sure what other options I might have. anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Add in your grid constructor this:

```
public function __construct() {
    ....
    $this->setNoFilterMassactionColumn(true);
}
```